# Getting a error message when trying to import a module that has been downloaded

Tags: python, import, module

Please forgive my ignorance but I am brand new to programming and have no one to go to for help.

I am currently trying to complete the course automate the boring stuff with python by Al Sweigart.

I am having issues importing modules, I did exactly as he recommended in his section A. Downloaded the file with all the modules for the course from his website, but I still cannot get to use them when I program. I get the following error messages.

I get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in 
import send2trash
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'send2trash''

I put the file in the Python 3.8 folder, I don't know if that is correct but some guidance would be great thank you in advance.

Comment: Whatever folder you put your module in should be included in `PYTHONPATH` variable to let interpreter know where to look for it. Alternatively, you can put it into your project folder and it should work this way too.